# Show that there exists a differentiable function $f$ s.t. $(f(x))^5+f(x)+x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives, inverse

Show that there exists a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t.

$(f(x))^5+f(x)+x=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

---

I am meant to use the Inverse Function Theorem for differentiability. However, I have no idea how to use it. I am sorry for the lack of any work. I genuinely have no idea.

Comment: You want the implicit function theorem, rather.

Comment: @user157227 $f(x) =0$ isn't a solution, since it becomes $\forall x ~~ x = 0$

Comment: @Mariano: I think inverse function is enough, since it is easy to isolate $x$ in the equation. The implicit function theorem would only give an $f$ _locally_, at least without some additional pleading.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the relation $y^5+y+x=0$; it defines $x$ as a function $g$ of $y$: $x=-(y^5+y)$. This function is a decreasing bijection from $\mathbf R$ to  $\mathbf R$ a since its derivative is $-(5y^4+1)\le -1<0$ and its limits at $\pm\infty$ are $\mp\infty$.

Let $f$ be its reciprocal; the relation $x=-(y^5+y)$ can be expressed as $$x=-\bigl(f(x)^5+f(x)\bigr).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The graph of your function would need to be a subset of the solution set of $y^5+y+x=0$, or in other words $x=-y^5-y$.

This set clearly determines $x$ as a function of $y$, so if $g(y)=-y^5-y$ has an inverse, the inverse function will work as the $f$ you're looking for.